# JASMINE not defined when I try to run Karma test runner

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to hook up the Karma test runner, using this [seed project](https://github.com/skusunam/angular-grunt-seed) as a model.

I pull the seed project in, build it, and the test runner works great.

When I edit the `karma.conf.js` config file to start including the files from my project, and move it to my current setup (outside the seed project), I get this error:

```
Running "karma:dev" (karma) task
ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
[ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined]
ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined
    at module.exports (C:\dev_AD_2014.01_PHASE1\config\karma-dev.conf.js:4:7)
    ...
```

I think I see what it's complaining about... in the seed project, it's karma config file is of an older format, that must have `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` defined somewhere:

**Seed Project karma config snippet**

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  '../app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  '../app/js/*.js',
  ....
];

exclude = ['karma.conf.js'];
...
```

My newer setup uses all the latest grunt plugins, and wants the config file wrapped in a module definition like so:

**My karma config snippet**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      JASMINE,
      JASMINE_ADAPTER,
      // library and vendor files
      '../dev/vendor/**/*.js'
      '../dev/app/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: ['**/*.e2e.js', '../config/*.js'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    ...
```

So it seems the problem is clear: the newer version(s) of some grunt plugins expect the modular definition, but are longer is setting up `JASMINE`, etc, as variables that are defined. That's my guess, but I'm a little lost on how to resolve this. I don't want to use the version of Karma that comes with the seed project if I can help it... I think it's version 0.4.4. I believe the newest stable version is 0.10.x.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use the latest stable Karma version (0.10.9) you should define Jasmine in the `frameworks` section and be sure to have karma-jasmine in the `plugins` section, in your karma configuration file.

Here's an example config file:

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true}
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],

    preprocessors: {

    },

    proxies: {

    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
              'Chrome'
              ],

    plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-script-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
            ],

    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Source: [Karma-runner docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html)

Comment: You have defined `frameworks` section twice in your config file which is not necessary.

Comment: @WojciechFrącz you're right! Thanks for pointing this out ;) I edited the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Including `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` in the files array is applicable to Karma versions 0.8.x and down. With newer versions of Karma, that is version 0.13 currently, just remove those 2 lines from the files array since you are already loading Jasmine as the framework(`framework=['jamsine']`).